# Odoo15 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

Tags: virtualenv, systemd, pypdf, pyenv, odoo-15

I'm new to Odoo.
I use pyenv to host odoo and all the dependencies. All under odoo system user, and I was able to start odoo service:

```
~# systemctl status odoo-15
● odoo-15.service - Odoo15
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/odoo-15.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-02-18 22:33:40 UTC; 6min ago
   Main PID: 61267 (python)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 79.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/odoo-15.service
             └─61267 /home/odoo/.pyenv/versions/odoo-15-env/bin/python /home/odoo/odoo-15/odoo-bin -c /home/odoo/.odoo_config
```

However, the service seems always stopped somehow automatically after around 1 hour due to PyPDF2 can't find:

```
Feb 18 16:10:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo systemd[1]: Started Odoo15.
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo odoo-15[58346]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo odoo-15[58346]:   File "/home/odoo/odoo-15/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo odoo-15[58346]:     import odoo
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo odoo-15[58346]:   File "/home/odoo/odoo-15/odoo/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo odoo-15[58346]:     import PyPDF2
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo odoo-15[58346]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo systemd[1]: odoo-15.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 18 17:19:32 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo systemd[1]: odoo-15.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

But I definitely have PyPDF2 in my pyenv

```
odoo@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-odoo:~/odoo-15$ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 17 2022, 17:59:57)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyPDF2
>>> PyPDF2.__version__
'1.26.0'
```

I feel it's something to do with my virtualenv config, but I'm bit lost here.
Could you help to enlighten me on what could be wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate virtual env and install Odoo requirements so:

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Or directly Install this module

```
pip3 install Pypdf2
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link , it fixed here on blogger

```
https://shilalg.blogspot.com/2019/07/importerror-no-module-named-pypdf2.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate your virtual environment and install the module within the environment, if you didn't, it won't recognize the installation.

Go to your odoo folder, as for original question

```
cd /home/odoo 
source odoo15-venv/bin/activate
 pip install PyPDF2  
 deactivate
 service odoo15 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use python3
try this command

apt-get install python3-pypdf2

Answer (score -1):

*Usually **happens when you forget to activate virtual env** for odoo.*

If you already have a configured **virtual environment** . start your **venv** before running odoo server.

If not . Then you have to install all the dependencies, *(which are in **requirement.txt** file in **odoo** directory).*

Navigate to odoo folder and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Hit enter. Let it install all packages and run your server again.